# Errno::EEXIST occurs when page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

When accessing a page cached action, I encountered the following error:

```
A Errno::EEXIST occurred in posts#index:

  File exists - [...]/public/cache
  [...]/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
```

This happens when Rails is trying to save the html cache into the public folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was symlinking the cache folder from capistrano's shared folder. However I forgot to manually create the actual folder under shared/ so Rails tries to recreate the actual folder, only to find the name has already been used by the symlink.

Making sure the symlinked cached folder actually exists stopped this problem.